# matplotlib animation, text not updating

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am new to animating with Matplotlib, and having a little trouble.  I would like to create an animation of particle positions, and I would like to display the frame number at each step.  I have created sample data at the beginning of my code snippet so the code is self-contained (normally my data is read in from a csv).

The problem - the displayed plot is completely blank.  However, if I comment out the return of time_text (i.e. change 'return patches, time_text' to 'return patches') everything works fine.  I assume the problem is in how I am updating the time_text, but I am stuck as to how to fix it.

---

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib import animation  
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  

box_size = 50  
radius = 1

df =pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.arange(50),np.arange(50),np.arange(50)]).T,
                          columns = ['x','y','frame'])

#set up the figure
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([0,box_size,0,box_size])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect(1)
time_text = ax.text(5, 5,'')

#initialization of animation, plot empty array of patches
def init():
    time_text.set_text('initial')
    return []

def animate(i):
    patches = []
    #data for this frame only
    data = df[df.frame == i]
    time_text.set_text('frame'+str(i))
    #plot circles at particle positions
    for idx,row in data.iterrows():
        patches.append(ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((row.x,row.y),radius,color= 'b',
                                               alpha = 0.5)))            
    return patches, time_text

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, repeat = False,
                               frames=int(df.frame.max()), interval=50, 
                                blit=True)
```

Comment: Possibly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594887/how-to-update-plot-title-with-matplotlib-using-animation) might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to let your initialization function return the `pyplot.text` object. You should also initiate the object that you want to modify at each call from the `anim` function.

Have a look at [ArtistAnimation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html), it might be better suited for what you are doing.

To avoid that many circles gather on the canvas, I would rather update the position of the path object instead of appending new ones at each iteration.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import animation  
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  

box_size = 50  
radius = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.arange(50),np.arange(50),np.arange(50)]).T,
                          columns = ['x','y','frame'])

#set up the figure
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([0,box_size,0,box_size])
ax = plt.gca()
time_text = ax.text(5, 5,'')

circle = plt.Circle((1.0,1.0), radius,color='b', alpha=0.5, facecolor='orange', lw=2)


#initialization of animation, plot empty array of patches
def init():
    time_text.set_text('initial')
    ax.add_patch( circle )
    return time_text, ax

def animate(i):
    #data for this frame only
    data = df[df.frame == i]
    time_text.set_text('frame' + str(i) )

    #plot circles at particle positions
    for idx,row in data.iterrows():
        circle.center = row.x,row.y

    return time_text, ax

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, repeat = False,
                               frames=int(df.frame.max()), interval=200, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: @mdriscoll Welcome to Stack Overflow. Observe that my solution introduces a problem, you will have to find a way to remove the old paths as new ones are being added.

Comment: Having init() function return time_text unfortunately does not help - it still returns a blank plot with no animation.  Is there a kwarg in FuncAnimation I am missing?

Comment: It should return at least 2 objects since the method expects an iterable. This is why I returned the `matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot`. The modified code I posted shows an animation with a changing text on both my computers, have you tried to run it?

Comment: Thanks - the code you posted does update the text.  However now the patches are just be appended to the same ax object, so I see the all of the  circles, rather than a moving circle.  Is there a way to clear the ax object? (this is why I had the line patches = [] in the animate function in the original code)