# Matplotlib animation.artistanimation showing all plots at once for inital figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-animation

I want to create live plots of my results and found this SO question which did most of the job: [Matplotlib animation update title using ArtistAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158604/matplotlib-animation-update-title-using-artistanimation)

BUT, when I start the script, the first figure shown is every figure at the same time (see screenshot below) What am I doing wrong? Also the axis is plotted twice but shifte (like in the initial figure) for each animation step. I would like to have the first plotted figure as the starting figure and then go to the next one after `interval=1000` miliseconds.

[image: Initial Figure]

I used the code from the other questions without any additions:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10,10)

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
container = []

for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    line, = ax.plot(a[:,i])
    title = ax.text(0.5,1.05,"Title {}".format(i), 
                    size=plt.rcParams["axes.titlesize"],
                    ha="center", transform=ax.transAxes, )
    container.append([line, title])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, container, interval=200, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

Using
`Python=3.7.16`
`matplotlib==3.5.3`

Comment: you should run plt.show() inside the for loop

Comment: The plot only shows the figure 0 and never continues.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the issue with a text editor like Sublime. I wonder if you're using Jupyter Notebook! If so, you need to add `%matplotlib notebook` at the top of the cell.

```
%matplotlib notebook # <- add this line

...

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,
                                container,
                                interval=1000, # <- change the interval here
                                blit=False)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: No, I am not using jupyter notebook. I also created a new environment where only matplotlib is installed.

Comment: But you say nothing about where you run your script.

Comment: I dont understand the question? What do you mean by "where do you run your script"? The script is executed with `python script.py` using the correct env

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue neither with such configuration (*e.g a script run from the terminal inside a virtual environement*). So can you try adding this line at the top of your script `import matplotlib;matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` ? Here is a list of the availables backends : https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html

Comment: Nothing changes when using different backends. But thanks for your help!